# c# split the proxies from ip:port to ip port

Tags: c#

I am making a code that gets proxies from a txt file.
but those proxies are in proxy:ip format.
Now I want it to use as:

```
WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("202.141.226.154", 8080);
```

But how can I get my proxies there & working?

Getting proxies:

```
    string proxy(string filee)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        Console.WriteLine("Found these proxies:");

        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
           new System.IO.StreamReader(filee);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            counter++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Total proxies:");
        Console.WriteLine(counter);
        file.Close();

        return "lol";
    }
```

Login with a proxy:

```
public static void MainLogin(string user, string pass)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.roblox.com/NewLogin");
    string postData = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}&submitLogin=Log+In&ReturnUrl=", user, pass);
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("202.141.226.154", 8080);
    myproxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
    request.Proxy = myproxy;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    reqCookie = RetrieveCookie(request);
}
```

So, how can I let them work together?
Thanks!

Comment: line.Split(':')[0] and line.Split(':')[1]

Comment: I wonder, how does one [split a string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: That file contains IPv4, only? Or as well IPv6 ?

Comment: "proxy:ip" should be "ip:port" ...

Comment: @Fildor only ipv4

Comment: I think it's rather interesting that you are reading files and creating proxies but don't know how to a split a string and do a loop. Homework perhaps?

Comment: @Juan Agreed.  Considering "how can i let them work together", I think it likely OP found this code on the web somewhere and doesn't know much about C#.  Doesn't look like homework to me, though.